# Ruby Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired

Tags: ruby

I'm consistently getting this error on several hosts on my machine, e.g.:

```
require 'open-uri'
open('https://google.com').read


Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:904:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:904:in `open'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:904:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:902:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:887:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:876:in `start'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:323:in `open_http'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:741:in `buffer_open'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:212:in `block in open_loop'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `open_loop'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:151:in `open_uri'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:721:in `open'
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Doesn't happen on others such as

```
open('https://twitter.com').read
```

Ruby 2.4.0 from rbenv and macOS 10.12.3. Tested also with Ruby 2.0.0 - the system version on macOS.

I get no error, and expected results when I `curl` or use Node's `request`. So this is not a blocked host, and my IP isn't blocked either.

Tried to reinstall Ruby, restart machine, and issue still occurs.

Any pointers?

Comment: What if you set open_timeout to something longer?

`open('https://google.com', open_timeout: 10).read`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like it's a an issue with how Ruby resolves DNS.

Added `require 'resolv-replace'` and now it's opening connections immediately.

Sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485369/116925
https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/597#issuecomment-40507119

Comment: /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34: warning: resolv-replace was loaded from the standard library, but will no longer be part of the default gems since Ruby 3.4.0. Add resolv-replace to your Gemfile or gemspec. Also contact author of zeitwerk-2.6.13 to add resolv-replace into its gemspec.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit another reason for this issue. Had a network where IPv6 is announced as routable but is not. That lead to IPv6 trying to be used resulting in the error.

So I had to disable IPv6.

For Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7:

```
# cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6.conf 
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
# sysctl -p
```

The `require 'resolv-replace'` also helped but my guess is that it just resolved to IPv4 instead so I don't want to limit app in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

I received error from rails application in docker container, and restarting docker service solved the problem:

```
sudo service docker start
```