# Firebase Cloud Function no longer receiving calls from ruby's Net:HTTP

Tags: ruby, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**Question**

Why, suddenly, do all calls to Firebase Cloud Function webhooks timeout when made via ruby's standard HTTP library (Net::HTTP)?

**Background**

This works just fine:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

uri = URI("https://postb.in/1570228026855-4628713761921?hello=world")
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
  req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.body = {a: 1}.to_json
  http.request(req)
end
```

However the same script does not work with a Cloud Function URL in place of the postb.in one.

Making the same POST request to the Cloud Function URL via cURL works. It's only when made via ruby Net:HTTP library where it's timing out:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `initialize': execution expired (Net::OpenTimeout)
```

This function has been called many times per second over the past several months, from a Ruby Net:HTTP Post without issue. And it suddenly stopped working last night. I've tested on multiple servers with ruby versions 2.3.8 and also 2.5.

The Cloud Function code is:

```
export const testHook = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log(request)
  response.status(200).send('works')
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include all relevant code in the question itself - do not link to outside resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being to add `require 'resolv-replace'` to the ruby script making use of Net::HTTP to make the HTTP POST. Found that thanks to: [Ruby Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036133/ruby-netopentimeout-execution-expired)

Why Net:HTTP is able to resolve postbin URLs but not Firebase ones, and why it was able to resolve Firebase ones successfully for many months until suddenly not, I can't explain.